# Scarpy outoput json

Tags: scrapy

I'm struggling with Scrapy to output only "hits" to a json file.  I'm new at this, so if there is just a link I should review, that might help (I've spent a fair amount of time googling around, still struggling) though code correction tips more welcome:).

I'm working off of the scrapy tutorial (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) , with the original code outputing a long list including field names and output like "field: output" where both blanks and found items appear.  I'd like only to include links that are found, and output them w/o the field name to a file.

For the following code I am trying, if I issue "scrapy crawl quotes2 -o quotes.json > output.json, it works but the quotes.json is always blank (i.e., including if I do "scrapy crawl quotes2 -o quotes.json").

In this case, as an experiment, I only want to return the URL if the string "Jane" is in the URL (e.g., /author/Jane-Austen):

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes2"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('a'):
            for i in quote.css('a[href*=Jane]::attr(href)').extract():
                if i is not None:
                    print(i)
```

I've tried "yield" and items options, but am not up to speed enough to make them work.  My longer term ambition to go to sites without having to understand the html tree (which may in and of itself be the wrong approach) and look for URLs with specific text in the URL string.

Thoughts?  Am guessing this is not too hard, but is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is happening because you are printing the items, you have to tell Scrapy explicitly to 'yield' them. 
But before that i don't see why you are looping through the anchor nodes instead of that you should loop over the quotes using css or XPath selectors, extract all the author links inside that quote and lastly check if that URL contains a specific String (Jane for you case).

```
for quote in response.css('.quote'):
   jane_url = quote.xpath('.//a[contains(@href, "Jane")]').extract_first()
   if jane_url is not None:

      yield {
       'url': jane_url
   }
```

Comment: Thx Rastacode, appreciate the help...I think another apostrophe is needed, so line of code would be  "jane_url = quote.xpath('.//a[contains(@href, "Jane")]').extract_first()    I had actually gotten it to work with yield, but was trying to figure out a way to filter out the field name from the output....no worries, though, appreciate the help!